# Show div after click and hide button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide a button after it has been clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">
    WELCOME
</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

In this fiddle you can see that the button is still visible after having been clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/vzmnJ/

How can I hide the button after click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Try this:

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  elem.style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv(this)" />
```

Comment: fiddle.jshell.net/:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined